# Is it possible to have multiple values at one element in a Numpy array?

Tags: python, numpy

I have a Numpy array of product data from a webshop. I want to add the list of product colors to a column, in which the first row has a string "color" (some products have multiple colors, while others only a single).

So for example:

```
[['Product_id'  'color']
['123'   'blue,black']
['124'   'black']
['125'   '0']]
```

Now, if I want to add two colors, 'green' and 'yellow' to the Product_id '125', is that achievable in a Numpy array?

Comment: Your array, as shown, has string `dtype`, something like "U20".  That is, it only contains strings.  It is possible to make an array with an `object` dtype.  Then the elements can be strings, numbers or lists.  But why not stick with lists?  Why are you using `numpy` for such a structure at all?

Comment: Consider using ```pandas``` for your purpose. You can try to generalize your question, from the little, that you said about your use case - it indeed sounds like not a ```numpy``` use case